# Python script stops when anything happens to command line prompt in Windows

Tags: python, windows, windows-console

I observed this. I just want to confirm it's normal. I have a Python script. It prints out some results to the console as it runs. If I click on the printout text or the scroll button, the script seems to stop running, until I let go of the button. Why would this happen? Is it because when I click, the script can't `print` anything? So the script stops?

Comment: Guess: the console does not update while you block it by interacting with the GUI.

Comment: It's a feature of the Windows console (conhost.exe) that writing to it will block while the user is selecting, scrolling, or has pressed the Pause key. If your script should keep running in this case, do the work on a separate thread and queue output to be printed by the main thread.

Comment: Note that you're not printing to cmd. That's just a shell that uses standard I/O. It is not the console or in any way responsible for the console. If you run python.exe from Explorer you won't see an instance of cmd as the parent; you'll see an associated instance of the console host process, conhost.exe.